# Shared hosting - Subdomain without main domain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I’m looking to host a site that will be accessed through a subdomain (mysite.mainsite.com) of another site (mainsite.com). I have set the main domain for my shared hosting account as mainsite.com and I’m about to set an A-record for mysite.mainsite.com to point to the IP of my server and add mysite.mainsite.com as a subdomain in cPanel.

The mainsite.com will however never be pointed to my server, so it somehow feels like I'm "cheating". My question is simply, should this work or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the viewpoint of the DNS system, it is absolutely ok. A hostname can contain a "`.`" without any problem.

This leads to the difference between *domains* and *zones*. If you have a host named `a.b.example.com`, which is registered by an `a.b` record in your zone `example.com`, you will have a `b.example.com` domain too, but only the `a.b.example.com` and `example.com` zones.

Of course, the [glue records](http://faq.domainmonster.com/dns/glue_record/) in your parent nameservers need to be set up accordingly.